# SQL where clause join not working

Tags: mysql

Apologies to begin with as I'm finding it really hard to explain what I want to do.

I have two tables - header and signoff

header looks something like this:

```
ID | Name | Description | Path     | Pnum   | DateC   | Prep | Assem |
60 | OSI  |  OSI-180    | blah.pdf | abc123 | 1/11/16 | 0    | 1     |
61 | test | test        | test.pdf | 12345  | 1/11/16 | 1    | 0     |
```

signoff like this:

```
ID | Badge | HeaderID | Recert |
24 | 204   | 60       | 0      |
25 | 201   | 60       | 1      |
26 | 201   | 61       | 0      |
```

HeaderID in signoff relates to the ID in header

I want to get header.ID, header.Name , header.path , header.description , header.datec , header.prep , header.assem , and signoff.Recertify.

The header.ID varies as I have multiple lines I want to get out, but for this example lets just say there's 2; 60 and 61. In the signoff table there are 2 badges that relate to 60 (204, and 201), and 1 that relates to 61 (201).

I want the statement to pull out all the lines for 60 and 61 but I don't want any duplicate lines (so both 60 and 61 show up only once) and to use the line where the badge relates if there is more than one. For example, it would show:

```
60, OSI, etc, etc, 1/11/16, 0, 1, 0 - relates to badge 204
61, test, etc, etc, 1/11/16, 1, 0, 0 - relates to badge 201
```

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT header.ID, header.Name , header.path , header.description , header.datec , header.prep , header.assem , header.testing , header.finish , signoff.Recertify,
from screens.header
LEFT JOIN screens.signoff ON header.ID=signoff.HeaderID
where header.ID = '60' and signoff.badge = '204'
```

(60 and 204 will change in the code that runs it)

The problem with this is if there is no entry for 204 against that HeaderID in signoff then it won't show.

What I'm essentially trying to do is populate a table and if someone needs re-certifying against a document (indicated by 1 in recert) then it to change the colour of the line. I have the badge number of the user in a variable.

Please can someone help with the SQL bit as I can't figure out how to get my data out.

Comment: put the badge test into the join clause, `join ... on id=headerid AND badge=204`, basically. that way even if there's no record on the right (signoff) side, you STILL get the stuff on the left (header).

Comment: What'e the logic for Recert? there are 2 signoffs for ID 60, with Recert 0 and Recert 1. What should show up and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditions on a LEFT JOIN should be in the ON clause

```
SELECT header.ID, header.Name , header.path , header.description , header.datec , header.prep , header.assem , header.testing , header.finish , signoff.Recertify,
FROM screens.header
LEFT JOIN screens.signoff 
    ON header.ID=signoff.HeaderID
    AND signoff.badge = '204'
WHERE  header.ID = '60'
```

Putting a condition on signoff in the WHERE clause means that you are 'killing' the LEFT JOIN and making it just a JOIN, since you are telling MySQL to only show results with `signoff.badge = '204'`, so that includes only results where there was a match to signoffs.